# PIC32 DMA (connected to SPI) interrupt not working

Tags: pic, spi, dma

I am working on my first PIC32 project on a custom board. I am utilizing a PIC32MZ2048EFH064 microcontroller which I am programming in MPLAB X IDE v5.40 (compiler: xc32 v2.41).

My goal is to receive data from an ADC (AD7768) via SPI (microcontroller as SPI slave). This worked so far.

But now I don't want to receive each sample separately in the SPI4 RX interrupt handler, but use the DMA controller (channel 0). I have configured the DMA controller so that a transfer is triggered when SPI4 has received data.

The SPI4 RX interrupt is still triggered periodically (LED2 blinking). But I never get an interrupt from the DMA controller (LED3 always off). Actually I want to get an interrupt when a block has been transferred (CHBCIE). But I have tried all other possible interrupts. None is triggered.

Does anyone have experience with PIC32 and DMA and has an idea what I am doing wrong?
Thanks a lot!

main.c:

```c
#include "main.h"

/*** DEVCFG0 ***/
#pragma config DEBUG =      ON
#pragma config JTAGEN =     OFF
#pragma config ICESEL =     ICS_PGx2
#pragma config TRCEN =      OFF
#pragma config BOOTISA =    MIPS32
#pragma config FECCCON =    OFF_UNLOCKED
#pragma config FSLEEP =     OFF
#pragma config DBGPER =     PG_ALL
#pragma config SMCLR =      MCLR_NORM
#pragma config SOSCGAIN =   GAIN_LEVEL_3
#pragma config SOSCBOOST =  ON
#pragma config POSCGAIN =   GAIN_LEVEL_3
#pragma config POSCBOOST =  ON
#pragma config EJTAGBEN =   NORMAL
#pragma config CP =         OFF

/*** DEVCFG1 ***/
#pragma config FNOSC =      SPLL
#pragma config DMTINTV =    WIN_127_128
#pragma config FSOSCEN =    OFF
#pragma config IESO =       OFF
#pragma config POSCMOD =    EC
#pragma config OSCIOFNC =   OFF
#pragma config FCKSM =      CSECME
#pragma config WDTPS =      PS1048576
#pragma config WDTSPGM =    STOP
#pragma config FWDTEN =     OFF
#pragma config WINDIS =     NORMAL
#pragma config FWDTWINSZ =  WINSZ_25
#pragma config DMTCNT =     DMT31
#pragma config FDMTEN =     OFF

/*** DEVCFG2 ***/
#pragma config FPLLIDIV =   DIV_3
#pragma config FPLLRNG =    RANGE_5_10_MHZ
#pragma config FPLLICLK =   PLL_POSC
#pragma config FPLLMULT =   MUL_50
#pragma config FPLLODIV =   DIV_2
#pragma config UPLLFSEL =   FREQ_24MHZ

/*** DEVCFG3 ***/
#pragma config USERID =     0xffff
#pragma config FMIIEN =     ON
#pragma config FETHIO =     ON
#pragma config PGL1WAY =    ON
#pragma config PMDL1WAY =   ON
#pragma config IOL1WAY =    ON
#pragma config FUSBIDIO =   ON

/*** BF1SEQ0 ***/
#pragma config TSEQ =       0xffff
#pragma config CSEQ =       0x0

void __ISR(_SPI4_RX_VECTOR) _SPI4_RX_InterruptHandler(void)
{
    SPI4_RX_InterruptHandler();
}

void __ISR(_DMA0_VECTOR) _DMA_Channel_0_InterruptHandler(void)
{
    DMA_Channel_0_InterruptHandler();
}

int main(void)
{
    /* Disable global interrupts */
    __builtin_disable_interrupts();
    
    /* Initialize GPIO */
    GPIO_Init();
    
    /* Reset AD7768 */
    GPIO_nRESET_Clear();     
    GPIO_nRESET_Set();
    
    /* Initialize SPI interfaces */
    SPI4_Init();
    
    /* Initialize DMA controllers */
    DMA_Init_Channel_0();
    
    /* Configure interrupt priorities */
    INTCONSET = _INTCON_MVEC_MASK;    
    IPC41SET = 0x4 | 0x0;  /* SPI4_RX: Priority 1 / Subpriority 0 */
    IPC33SET = 0x4 | 0x0;  /* DMA0: Priority 1 / Subpriority 0 */
    
    /* Enable global interrupts */
    __builtin_enable_interrupts();
    
    /* Endless loop */    
    while(1)
    {
        GPIO_LED1_Toggle();
    }

    /* Execution should not come here during normal operation */
    return (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

main.h:

```c
#ifndef _MAIN_H    /* Guard against multiple inclusion */
#define _MAIN_H

#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <xc.h>
#include <sys/attribs.h>
#include "gpio.h"
#include "spi4.h"
#include "dma.h"

/* 
 * Translates a kernel virtual address in KSEG0 or KSEG1 to a real
 * physical address and back.
 */
typedef unsigned long _paddr_t; /* a physical address */
typedef unsigned long _vaddr_t; /* a virtual address */
#define KVA_TO_PA(v)     ((_paddr_t)(v) & 0x1fffffff)
#define PA_TO_KVA0(pa)    ((void *) ((pa) | 0x80000000))
#define PA_TO_KVA1(pa)    ((void *) ((pa) | 0xa0000000))

int main(void);

#endif /* _MAIN_H */
```

spi4.c:

```c
#include "main.h"

uint32_t __attribute__((coherent)) spi4RxBuffer[SPI4_RX_BUFFER_SIZE] = { 0 };

void SPI4_Init(void)
{
    /* Disable SPI4 interrupts */
    IEC5bits.SPI4EIE = 0;       // Fault interrupt
    IEC5bits.SPI4RXIE = 0;      // Rx interrupt
    IEC5bits.SPI4TXIE = 0;      // Tx interrupt

    /* Stop and reset SPI */
    SPI4CON = 0;

    /* Clear receive buffer */
    uint32_t rData = SPI4BUF;
    rData = rData;

    /* Clear interrupt flags */
    IFS5bits.SPI4EIF = 0;       // Fault interrupt
    IFS5bits.SPI4RXIF = 0;      // Rx interrupt
    IFS5bits.SPI4TXIF = 0;      // Tx interrupt

    /* Clear the overflow */
    SPI4STATbits.SPIROV = 0;

    /* Configure control register */
    SPI4CONbits.FRMEN = 1;      // Framed SPI support
    SPI4CONbits.FRMSYNC = 1;    // Frame sync pulse input (slave mode))
    SPI4CONbits.FRMPOL = 1;     // Frame pulse is active-high
    SPI4CONbits.DISSDO = 1;     // SDO4 pin is not used by the module
    SPI4CONbits.MODE32 = 1;     // 32-bit mode
    SPI4CONbits.SSEN = 1;       // SS4 pin used for slave mode
    SPI4CONbits.SRXISEL = 3;    // SPI4RXIF is set when the buffer is full
    
    /* Enable receive done interrupt */
    IEC5bits.SPI4RXIE = 1;

    /* Enable SPI4 */
    SPI4CONbits.ON = 1;
}

void SPI4_RX_InterruptHandler(void)
{
    GPIO_LED2_Set();

    /* Clear Rx interrupt flag */
    IFS5CLR = _IFS5_SPI4RXIF_MASK;
    
    GPIO_LED2_Clear();
}
```

spi4.h:

```c
#ifndef _SPI4_H    /* Guard against multiple inclusion */
#define _SPI4_H

#include "main.h"

#define SPI4_RX_BUFFER_SIZE                     8
    
uint32_t __attribute__((coherent)) spi4RxBuffer[SPI4_RX_BUFFER_SIZE];

void SPI4_Init(void);
void SPI4_RX_InterruptHandler(void);

#endif /* _SPI4_H */
```

dma.c:

```c
#include "main.h"

void DMA_Init_Channel_0(void)
{
    /* Disable DMA channel 0 interrupt */
    IEC4bits.DMA0IE = 0;

    /* Clear interrupt flag */
    IFS4bits.DMA0IF = 0;
    
    /* Enable DMA controller */
    DMACONbits.ON = 1;
    
    /* Configure DMA channel 0 source address */
    DCH0SSA = KVA_TO_PA(&SPI4BUF);
    
    /* Configure DMA channel 0 desination address */
    DCH0DSA = KVA_TO_PA(&spi4RxBuffer);
    
    /* Number of source bytes */
    DCH0SSIZ = 4;
    
    /* Number of destination bytes */
    DCH0DSIZ = SPI4_RX_BUFFER_SIZE*4;
    
    /* Number of bytes transferred per event */
    DCH0CSIZ = 4;
    
    /* Channel is continously enabled */
    DCH0CONbits.CHAEN = 1;
    
    /* Start channel cell transfer on SPI4 RX complete interrupt */
    DCH0ECONbits.CHSIRQ = _SPI4_RX_VECTOR;
    DCH0ECONbits.SIRQEN = 1;
    
    /* Enable channel block transfer complete interrupt */
    DCH0INTbits.CHBCIE = 1;
    
    /* Enable DMA channel 0 interrupt */
    IEC4bits.DMA0IE = 1;
    
    /* Enable DMA channel 0 */
    DCH0CONbits.CHEN = 1;    
}

void DMA_Channel_0_InterruptHandler(void)
{
    GPIO_LED3_Set();
    
    /* Clear interrupt flags */
    DCH0INTCLR = 0xFF;
    IFS4CLR = _IFS4_DMA0IF_MASK;
    
    GPIO_LED3_Clear();
}
```

dma.h:

```c
#ifndef _DMA_H    /* Guard against multiple inclusion */
#define _DMA_H

#include "main.h"

void DMA_Init_Channel_0(void);
void DMA_Channel_0_InterruptHandler(void);

#endif /* _DMA_H */
```

Comment: I just recognized that I had to add `__attribute__((coherent))` to the target buffer (`spi4RxBuffer[SPI4_RX_BUFFER_SIZE]`). The DMA is now writing to the buffer and the CHBCIF flag in the DCH0INT register is set. However, the ISR is still never entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Simply adjust the priorities, e.g. the following is working:

```c
void __ISR(_DMA0_VECTOR, IPL3SRS) _DMA_Channel_0_InterruptHandler(void)
{
    DMA_Channel_0_InterruptHandler();
}

...

IPC33bits.DMA0IP = 3; // set DMA channel 0 priority to 3
IPC33bits.DMA0IS = 1; // set DMA channel 0 sub-priority to 1
```